# Pandas series.groupby().apply( .sum() ), .sum() not summing values

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have the following test code:
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'MONTH': [1,2,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
                   'HOUR': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
                   'CIGFT': [np.NaN,12000,2500,73300,73300,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,12000,100,100,15000,2500,np.NaN,15000,11000,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]})

cigs = pd.DataFrame()
cigs['cigsum'] = df.groupby(['MONTH','HOUR'])['CIGFT'].apply(lambda c: (c>=0.0).sum())
cigs['cigcount'] = df.groupby(['MONTH','HOUR'])['CIGFT'].apply(lambda c: (c>=0.0).count())

df.fillna(value='-', inplace=True)
cigs['cigminus'] = df.groupby(['MONTH','HOUR'])['CIGFT'].apply(lambda c: (c>=0.0).sum())

tfile = open('test_COUNT_manual.txt', 'a')
tfile.write(cigs.to_string())
tfile.close()
```

I wind up with the following results:

The dataframe:

```
  CIGFT  HOUR  MONTH
```

0       NaN     0      1

1   12000.0     0      2

2    2500.0     0      3

3   73300.0     0      1

4   73300.0     0      1

5       NaN     0      1

6       NaN     0      1

7       NaN     0      1

8       NaN     0      1

9   12000.0     0      2

10    100.0     0      3

11    100.0     0      2

12  15000.0     0      2

13   2500.0     0      3

14      NaN     0      2

15  15000.0     0      1

16  11000.0     0      1

17      NaN     0      1

18      NaN     0      1

19      NaN     0      1

20      NaN     0      1

21      NaN     0      1

The results in the write to file:

```
        cigsum  cigcount  cigminus
```

MONTH HOUR

1     0          4        14        14

2     0          4         5         5

3     0          3         3         3

My issue is that the .sum() is not summing the values.  It is doing a count of the non null values.  When I replace the null values with a minus, the .sum()
produces the same result as the count().
So what do I use to get the sum of the values if .sum() does not do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Series.sum()** -> return the sum of the series values excluding **NA/null** values by default as mentioned in official docs.

You are getting series in lambda function each time, just apply sum function to series in lambda will give you correct result.

Do this,

```
cigs['cigsum'] = df.groupby(['MONTH','HOUR'])['CIGFT'].apply(lambda c: c.sum())
```

Result of this code will be,

```
MONTH  HOUR
1      0       172600.0
2      0        39100.0
3      0         5100.0
```